# BCNF and Nontrivial Functional Dependencies

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to understand BCNF and Non trivial FDs but I'm kind of confused. I've currently designed the following database and to my understanding this should be BCNF.

Can you PLEASE provide feedback if indeed it is? Note that * implies primary key and a user can't bid on the same item at the same time. An item can have multiple categories. first_bid is unique to each item and means minimum required bid amount. start, end are dates for the auction.

> Item(item_id*, name, current_bid, buy_price, first_bid, num_bids, seller_id, start, end, description) 
>   Bids(buyer_id*, time*,amount, item_id) 
>   Users(user_id*, location, country, rating) 
>  Category(cat_id*,
>   cat_name) 
>  ItemCategory(item_id*, category_id*)

Could you also please tell me what would be the Non trivial functional dependencies for each relation?

Comment: My concern is about the second table. Please guys :( I've already spent 17 hours on this....

Answer (score 4):

An example of a trivial dependency:  In the bids table,  (buyer_id, time) determines time.  It's trivial because it's part of the input.

An example of a non trivial dependency:  In the Category table, cat_id determines cat_name, presumably.  If it doesn't then cat_id can't be the key.

If you will tell us all the FDs, we'll tell you which ones are non trivial.

As an additional handle on BCNF,  here's a handy rule:  any table that has only one candidate key and is in 3NF is also in BCNF.  Do any of these tables have alternative candidate keys, other than the ones you've stated?

The Users table might not be in 3NF.  Does Location determine Country?

Comment: Thanks so much Walter Milly! Well location and country are not dependent to each other, user can write anything to both areas. Like location: "hell", country: "bermuda"

I am not sure which are all FDs for each table but to my understanding, since there are no other candidate keys (I couldn't see any more, can you see more?), then only nontrivial dependencies should be the key ones determining the rest of attributes, is that right?

Comment: So nontrivial DFs would be:

item_id -> name, current_bid, buy_price, first_bid, num_bids, seller_id, start, end, description
buyer_id, time -> amount, item_id
user_id->location, country, rating
cat_id->cat_name
item_id->category_id

Comment: Discovering FDs is not about database design skills.  It's about how well one understands the subject matter and the data.  It's your data, not mine.  You tell me what the FDs are.

Comment: You don't derive the FDs from the database design.  You derive the database design from the FDs.  You derive the FDs from analyzing the data.